# Scalar products and partitions of Hypercubes

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, coordinate-systems, integer-partitions

My questions relate to scalar products defined in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and partitions of hypercubes. Take $s \in \mathbb{R}$, $\xi, \eta \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

My first question is why is it possible to state that up to a change of coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ we may then suppose that the scalar product can be written as: $$\langle \xi- \eta,;x \rangle = (\xi_{1}-\eta_{1})x_{1}$$ where $x = (x_{1},...,x_{n})$ and $(\xi - \eta) = (\xi_{1}-\eta_{1},...,\xi_{n}-\eta_{n})$ and $\langle \cdot \rangle$ denotes the scalar product.

Secondly, if we consider the hypercube O = $H_{R}(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_{i,\beta_{i}}) = (\alpha_{1},\beta_{1}) \times \prod_{i=2}^{n}(\alpha_{i}, \beta_{i})$ and the following partition:

We divide $(\alpha_{1}, \beta_{1})$ into intervals of length $(\beta_{1}-\alpha_{1})2^{-m}$ where $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Each of these intervals is then subdivided into two parts of equal length $(\beta_{1}-\alpha_{1})2^{-(m+1)}$. The union of the first(resp. the second) subintervals is denoted by $I_{m}$(resp. $J_{m}$). We denote by $$O_{1}^{m} = I_{m} \times \prod_{i=2}^{n}(\alpha_{i}, \beta_{i})$$ $$O_{2}^{m} = J_{m} \times \prod_{i=2}^{n}(\alpha_{i}, \beta_{i})$$ then $\lim\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty} \text{meas } O_{1}^{m} = \lim\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty} \text{meas }O_{2}^{m} = \frac{1}{2}\text{meas } O$.

My question is how does it follow that if $x \in O_{1}^{m}$ then $\langle \xi- \eta;x \rangle \in I_{m}$?

Thanks for any assistance. Please ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: Some context is missing, but it's hard to know what; if you could give a reference to the source of these claims, that would help. Some remarks: $s$ is introduced but never used in your question. You introduce hypercube $H_R(x)$, but never use $x$ in its construction.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am studying the paper http://caa.epfl.ch/publications/9-Boccardo-Dacorogna1984.pdf, refer to page 8 and 9. Is $\langle \xi- \eta,;x \rangle = (\xi_{1}-\eta_{1})x_{1}$ maybe a standard type of transformation of the coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? Also the hypercube is centred at $x$ so each interval has the $x$ component in the centre of the interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noticed in the comments there are some inconsistency of notations in the question but I will try nevertheless to give an answer to your question.
To do so I had to make some assumption on what is the precise context. I choose what seems to me to make sense. I hope it fits with what you really need.

For the first question: If the vectors $\xi$ and $\eta$ are fixed then $\xi-\eta$ is a fixed vector and we can build a base $(\xi-\eta,\zeta^{(2)},\zeta^{(3)},\ldots,\zeta^{(n)})$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. In this base $\xi-\eta=(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$, so it is clear that $\langle \xi-\eta, x\rangle= (\xi_1-\eta_1) x_1$. Actually with this choice we even have $\langle \xi-\eta, x\rangle=x_1$.

Now for the second question I assume that the last equality holds.
I guess that when you write 
$H_{R}(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_{i,\beta_{i}})$
you actually mean
$H(\alpha,\beta) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_{i},\beta_{i}).$
I also guess that we consider the hypercube 
$$O=H(\eta,\xi)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(\eta_{i},\xi_{i}).$$
Then $x\in O_{1}^{m} = I_{m} \times \prod_{i=2}^{n}(\eta_{i}, \xi_{i})$ implies $x_1\in I_m$.
But by our assumptions this is precisely $\langle \xi-\eta, x\rangle\in I_m$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying to understand how exactly this coordinate transformation is carried out. Could you give me an idea of how you would build this base $(\xi -\eta,...,\zeta^{(n)})$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and how it gives $\xi - \eta = (1,0,....,0)$? Also just to make the notation clear. $H_{R}(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_{i},\beta_{i})$ refers to the product of the intervals $(\alpha_{i},\beta_{i})$ which has the $x$ component $x_{i}$ at it's centre. This is the notation used in the paper I am studying.

Comment: Let's call $\zeta^{(1)}:=\xi-\eta$. It spans the line $L:=\mathbb{R} \zeta^{(1)}$.
Consider $H$ an hyperplane of $\mathbb{R}^d$ not containing $\zeta^{(1)}$. We have that $\mathbb{R}^d=L\oplus H$.
Consider a base $(\zeta^{(2)},\ldots,\zeta^{(n)})$ of $H$.
Now when we add $\zeta^{(1)}$ to this set of vector we still have a free set of vector because $\zeta^{(1)}\notin H$, so we have a base of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Now $\xi-\eta=\zeta^{(1)}=1 \zeta^{(1)}+ 0 \zeta^{(2)} + \cdots +0 \zeta^{(n)}$, so the coordinate of $\xi-\eta$ in this base are $(1,0,\cdots,0)$.

Comment: What is $R$ in the notation $H_R(x)$? You say that $x_i$ is at the center of the interval $(\alpha_i,\beta_i)$. This is not enough information to determine uniquely $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$.
One condition which could make sense is that $R$ is the length of the sides of your hypercube, more precisely $\beta_i-\alpha_i=R$. This with the condition with $x$ would determine uniquely $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes for any choice of $H$ not containing $L$ then $H$ and $L$ will span $\mathbb{R}^n$.